# How to Restrict referenced tables in LINQ to SQL Entity Framework?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Entity Framework and Linq to SQL to select data from a database table. In my result object I am getting the tables being referenced by the selected table. Is there any way to restrict the referenced tables and get only the selected table. Below is my code.

```
var routeMaster = (from Ec_RouteMaster in travelServicesDBEntities.ExtraComfort_RouteMaster where (Ec_RouteMaster.Source == flights.OriginCode && Ec_RouteMaster.Destination == flights.DestinationCode && Ec_RouteMaster.AirCraftType == flights.AircraftType && Ec_RouteMaster.Switch == "1") select Ec_RouteMaster).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want data only from ExtraComfort_RouteMaster. But EF fetched data also from the tables referenced by the primary key of ExtraComfort_RouteMaster. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) and check the sections about lazy loading.